# Moving divisions to the opposite side

Tags: divisibility

The question I have to answer is:

$\frac {4V_3} 2 = 108V$, where I need to get $V_3$ on its own.

When moving the 4 and the 2 to the other side will it be:

$(108 \cdot 2)/4$

or

$(108/4) \cdot 2 $

Comment: Is it $$\frac{4V_3}{2}=108V$$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If so then we get $$V_3=\frac{2\cdot 108V}{4}=54V$$

Comment: That's it, thank you so much!